# Spring MVC + Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, frameworks

Im using Spring MVC. Recently im getting sick of ugly javascript code, debugging, flexibility and maintenance. jQuery is not enought to make me happy. Is there any good framework that can cope with that?

Comment: Whenever you do web application . You have to live with that..

Answer (score 1):

There are several javascript frameworks that you can choose. I would suggest MVC frameworks:

http://www.infoq.com/research/top-javascript-mvc-frameworks

http://jonathanmh.com/best-javascript-mvc-frameworks-2013-2014/

You will be able to provide a better structure in our web applications.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Angular js?

It's a javascript framework which uses jQuery but it's so much more than that. Give it a look

https://angularjs.org/